# How to implement onWindowFocusChange() method in a Dialog (Android)

Tags: android, inheritance, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I need to use the method `onWindowFocusChange()` to close system dialogs in an `AlertDialog`, so I've decided to extend `AlertDialog` and implement that method.

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends AlertDialog {    
    private Context context;

    protected MyAlertDialog(Context context) {
       super(context);
       this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if (!hasFocus) {
            Intent closeDialogs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            context.sendBroadcast(closeDialogs);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call to `create()` or `show()` from `AlertDialog.Builder`, these methods get back an `AlertDialog` but not a `MyAlertDialog` object and `onWindowsFocusChanged()` is not executed. Obviously I can't cast `AlertDialog` to `MyAlertDialog`.

```
 AlertDialog dialog = new MyAlertDialog(this);

 MyAlertDialog.Builder builder = new MyAlertDialog.Builder(this);
 builder.setMessage(...);
 builder.setCancelable(false);
 builder.setNeutralButton(...)
 builder.show(); // Returns AlertDialog
 // dialog = builder.show(); -> dialog doesn't execute onWindowsFocusChanged()
 // dialog = (MyAlertDialog) builder.show() -> Not allowed (ClassCastException)
```

So, how can I create and show an `MyAlertDialog` or another way to close system dialogs when a `Dialog` is showing? I have looked for info but I don't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `onWindowFocusChanged` you have to create a Dialog layout in xml with 2 buttons, create a Dialog class and extend Dialog, and set the Dialog's content view with it.

xml Dialog (myDialog.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:gravity="end">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxWidth="128dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxWidth="128dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Dialog class:

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {
    private Context context;

    public F50Dialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (!hasFocus) {
            Intent closeDialogs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialogs);
        }
    }
}
```

Create your dialog in the Activity:

```
private void myDialog() {

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.myDialog, null, false);

        final MyDialog alert = new MyDialog(this);
        final EditText input = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.password);

        spin.setAdapter(mOperatorsAryAdapter);

        alert.setContentView(promptsView);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setTitle("Password Required");
        alert.findViewById(R.id.btn_no).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (???) {
                    alert.dismiss();
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
```

Now the onWindowFocusChanged will fire!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It answers my question and it should work.
However, I tell you how I have solved it: When the activity loses the focus (a dialog is shown, a menu with submenus shown from the action bar, etc.) in the `onWindowFocusChanged()`method I launch a service with a thread that is running every 300 milliseconds to close system dialogs. The service (and the  thread) are stopped when the activity gains the focus again in the `onWindowFocusChanged()`method. Thus, system dialogs are never shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the overriden method:

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (!hasFocus) {
            Intent closeDialogs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialogs);
        }
    }
```

To the activity itself.

And use the **AlertDialog** class. Whenever a system dialog appears, it will be closed by the call to the method that happens inside the activity, no need to inherit from the AlertDialog class.

Comment: I already have `onWindowsFocusChanged()` inside the activity but when a `Dialog` is showing it takes the focus and the activity loses it. So it is necessary implement `onWindowsFocusChanged()` again inside the `Dialog` to keep closing system dialogs while it's showing.